# How can I get search engines to index dynamically generated pages

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, dynamic, sitemap

I'm trying to create a blog ..and for every entry I have a template page called entry.php
I create the pages by creating a link from my home page like  this

```
mywebsite.com/entry.php?title=My Title&content=This is my blog
```

This link is passed to entry.php and a page is generated on the fly based on the link i wrote but search engines wont index these.

Do I really have to create a unique page for every entry I create?

Do sites like youtube have individual pages for every single video or are they generated dynamically like im trying to do. If so how do the videos show up in search results?

Ive heard something called .htaccess or sitemap.xml can be used for this I have no idea what these are though.

Comment: If your blog page is generated based on what you put in title= and content= only, you should have another way for search engines to find your content. Is there an index page or something that links to the different blog posts?

Answer (score 3):

#### Learn about `.htaccess`

There are a lot of generators for `.htaccess` and you can use one of them. The best thing to do is, using a `.htaccess` file, create the paths this way:

```
mywebsite.com/entry.php?title=My Title&content=This is my blog
```

Change them to:

```
mywebsite.com/My Title/This is my blog
```

And the code for the same is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /entry.php?title=$1&content=$2 [L]
```

#### Websites offering generators:

- [.htaccess redirect](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/)
- [Mod Rewrite Generator](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mod_rewrite-rewriterule-generator.shtml)
- [Search Engine Optimization Tools » mod_rewrite rewriterule generator](http://www.htaccessredirect.net/)

Answer (score 1):

As long as the page **is linked to from *somewhere***, search engines will find the page. It does not matter how the page is generated. A link is a URL, when requesting this URL the browser or any other client (including search engines) receive the page content, period. It works like any other regular page, search engines don't know or care what happens behind the scenes to generate this page.